# How to save a Javascript array as a .txt file

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good day all.

the following code quite easily saves the "const rows" array as a .txt file

```js
function exportAdjacency() {

            const rows = [
                [-1, 183, 294, -1],
                [183, -1, 171, 306],
                [294, 171, -1, 187],
                [-1, 306, 187, -1]
            ];


            const csvContent = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${rows
                .map((e) => e.join(","))
                .join("\n")}`;
            const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
            link.setAttribute("download", "data.txt");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click()
        }
```

However, in my case, my array is not formatted as in the code above. In fact, I have a 1 D array of, in this case, 16 numbers, which I need to feed into the above code.

I have tried to segment the array using array.slice as below

```
function func() {

    var article = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];

    var heading = article.slice(0, 4);
    var heading2 = article.slice(4, 8);
    var heading3 = article.slice(8, 12);
    var heading4 = article.slice(12, 16);
        
    alert(heading)
    alert(heading2)
    alert(heading3)
    alert(heading4)
            
}
```

The alerts just confirm that the segmentation was successful.

My question is, how do I segment the 1 D array and feed its contents into the

"const rows" of the first code example?

I have tried changing the first code snippet to rather accept something like

"array rows" but this doesn't work.

Now in this example, the 1 D array has 16 elements. In the general case, it could have any number of elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Please recreate the example in a sandbox so we can see first hand what you are talking about.

Comment: _I have tried changing the first code snippet to rather accept..._ and _1 D array_ <-- makes me think you only need to write your 1-dimensional array into a file. And, there is no need to transform the 1D array into 2D array (like `rows`). If so, change: `${rows.map((e) => e.join(",")).join("\n")}` to `${articles.map(e => e.join(",")).concat("\n")}` and give it a try. If you need the 1D array to be transformed into the 2D array, please change the title of the question accordingly.

Comment: Why not just save it as JSON? Then you have a solution for every array type in a one liner

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Its a bit complicated. Essentially I am building an indoor navigation app. The app is coded in Java. I use a Dijikstra code in the Java app. This code requires the Adjacency Matrix in the form of a simple text file. I then have a Tool built in HTML5 and javascript. The tool enables me to plot all the nodes and paths through the nodes. In this tool the elements of the Adjacency Matrix come out as a 1 d javascript array. So if I can export this array as a 2 d text file I can just drop it into the java code and Im good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The slice() method returns selected elements in an array, as a new array.

The slice() method does not change the original array.

const variable cannot be reassign, use let, to assign segment to rows (let),
And use splice() method overwrites the original array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am aware of what slice does. I use slice() to break the 1 D array into sub-arrays. This part seems to work fine. I am then trying to use these new arrays to populate the "const rows". I am not familiar with const.  Thanks  - Paul